# Python if branch “expected an indented block”

Tags: python

Sorry if i am still newbie, i get an indentation error at line 13, please help me. I already read much article from google especially stackoverflow.

```
list1 = []
long = False
count = 0
TVR_count = 0

for i in range(0,len(df1Lat)):
    for j in range(0, len(df_ANTV)):
        if (df1Lat.start_time.values[i][0:5] == df_ANTV.daypart_variable.values[j][0:5]): 
            if (df1Lat.end_time.values[i][0:5] == df_ANTV.daypart_variable.values[j][0:5]):
                df1Lat.TVR_total = df_ANTV.TVR.values[j];
                list1.append(df1Lat.iloc[i];
            else:
                long = True
                count += 1

        elif (long == True):
            count += 1
            TVR_count += df_ANTV.TVR.values[j]            
            if ((str(df1Lat.end_time.values[i])[0:5]) == (str(df_ANTV.daypart_variable.values[j])[0:5])):
                long = False
                df1Lat.TVR_total = TVR_count/count
                list1.append(df1Lat.iloc[i])
                count = 0
                TVR_count=0
        else:
            pass

dfLat = pd.DataFrame(list1)
dfLat[['date','channel','product','start_time','end_time','TVR_total']].head(60)
```

Comment: `list1.append(df1Lat.iloc[i];` you are missing the right parenthesis

Comment: I think the main problem is that you forgot to close the parenthesis in `list1.append(df1Lat.iloc[i];`

Comment: wow thanks for the answer, i really apreciate. huge thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a closing bracket on this line `list1.append(df1Lat.iloc[i];`
Replace it with this: `list1.append(df1Lat.iloc[i])`

Answer (score 0):

Here's some points to improve your code overall:

- Line10: `df1Lat.TVR_total = df_ANTV.TVR.values[j]` instead `df1Lat.TVR_total = df_ANTV.TVR.values[j];`
- Line11: `list1.append(df1Lat.iloc[i])` instead `list1.append(df1Lat.iloc[i];`
- [What are the comprehensive lint checkers for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611776/what-are-the-comprehensive-lint-checkers-for-python)
- Follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines, it's sort of widely standard when coding python

But the most important, code should be like a good book, if I was going try to understand your little code fragment, do you think the chosen words would help me to understand its meaning? :)